# How to simulate a mouseclick on bxslider's default next slide button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bxslider

Following problem:

The default "Next" button of the bx slider looks like this in HTML:

```
<a class="bx-next" href="">
```

When I click on that button with the mouse everything works fine. I created a little function that returns "clicked" in the console after clicking the button (only works for mouse click):

```
$('a.bx-next').click(function () {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Normally I use `$('selector').click()` to simulate a click and it works. But `$('a.bx-next').click()` in this example just doesn't work and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery's `.click()` is not the same as the native `.click()` method. jQuery's adds a "click" event listener, where as the native method trigger's a click. Either use `.get(0)` to escape from jQuery, or use the `.trigger("click")` method.

Comment: Thx but $('a.bx-next').get(0).click(); led to this error: "TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined" and $('a.bx-next').trigger('click'); just didn't work...